# Iterating over core-data passed to a view

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, viewcontroller

I am passing data to the view using this method:

```
nextViewController = [[AfricanSwallowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AfricanSwallowView" bundle:nil];
((InstructionsViewController *)nextViewController).byTheHusk = byTheHusk;
```

I am trying to iterate over the values on the view that byTheHusk gets passed to.

I have tried several versions of `NSLog(@"%@", byTheHusk.name);` and using `objectAtIndexPath` etc. with no luck

Is there a way to access the the objects entries attributes in a `while` or `for` loop style structure?

The closest I can get is:

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:0];
NSLog(@"%@",[[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description]);
```

which results in:

`ByTheHusk[7880:207] (null)`

Which means there are 207 entries. Is that right? and that ByTheHusk is getting passed correctly?

I am a noob to this all so thanks for any help!!!

Bo

Comment: What kind of object is `byTheHusk`? Why do you want to iterate of a collection of managed objects?

Comment: core data object passed created and icluded frombyTheHusk.h/m

Comment: There is no such thing as a "core data object". There are instances of NSManagedObject, NSManagedObjectContext, etc. Sorry but the details are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out through some eduction and trial and error and error and error.

But I got it!!!!

```
NSMutableArray* annotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Save our fetched data to an array  
[self setEventArray: mutableFetchResults];  
[mutableFetchResults release];  
[request release]; 
//NSLog(@"%d",[eventArray count]);

for (int i = 0; i < [eventArray count]; i++) {
    //NSLog(@"%@",[[eventArray objectAtIndex:i] name]);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    double latNum = [[[eventArray objectAtIndex:i] latitude] doubleValue];
    theCoordinate.latitude = latNum;
    double lonNum = [[[eventArray objectAtIndex:i] longitude] doubleValue];
    theCoordinate.longitude = lonNum;
    //-------------------------
    MyAnnotation* tempAnnotation=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    tempAnnotation.coordinate=theCoordinate;
    tempAnnotation.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[eventArray objectAtIndex:i] name]];
    tempAnnotation.subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[eventArray objectAtIndex:i] name]];
    //-------------------------
    [mapView addAnnotation:tempAnnotation];
    [annotations addObject:tempAnnotation];
}
```

Put it in an array and roll over it... thanks all for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing a NSManagedObjectContext object with a NSManagedObject object.

This code segment:

```
nextViewController = [[AfricanSwallowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AfricanSwallowView" bundle:nil];
((InstructionsViewController *)nextViewController).byTheHusk = byTheHusk;
```

... looks like an attempt to hand of a NSManagedObjectContext from one view controller to another. However, the attempted cast is probably throwing things off. It should probablylook like this:

```
InstructionsViewController *nextViewController = [[AfricanSwallowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AfricanSwallowView" bundle:nil];
nextViewController.byTheHusk = self.byTheHusk; //assuming that byTheHusk is a property of the current view controller.
```

I'm guessing that `InstructionsViewController` is a tableview controller using a NSFetchedResultsController and configured to fetch from the `byTheHusk` managed object context.

If so, then getting a `null` return from this code:

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:0];
NSLog(@"%@",[[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description]);
```

... probably indicates that the `fetchedResultsController` finds no objects when it fetches. In any case, it would not log the `byTheHusk` object but just the first NSManagedObject instance that the fetch found.

> ByTheHusk[7880:207] (null)
>
> Which means there are 207 entries. Is that right? and that ByTheHusk
>   is getting passed correctly?

No. In this case `ByTheHusk` is the name of the app/library and the numbers are IIRC the line and block offsets in the object file. They have nothing to do with object being logged. The `(null)` simply means that the statement `[[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description]` does not return an object of any kind.

Not sure what your problem is but fixing the first bit of code above will help.

Comment: Instructive for sure! I will look at that. It is not being passed to a table view but a view with labels, and the desired result is: `
textFieldA1 = byTheHusk.objectAtIndex0.name
textFieldA2 = byTheHusk.objectAtIndex0.typeofswallow 
textFieldB1 = byTheHusk.objectAtIndex1.name
textFieldB2 = byTheHusk.objectAtIndex1.typeofswallow`

Comment: `byTheHusk` must be a NSArray because only arrays responds to `objectAtIndex:`. The objects in the array have to be your managed objects that have a key of `typeofswallow` that returns a string value.